# Django - How to link to a legacy database via intermediary?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have to integrate a legacy design with my Django project and I am looking for some advice on using an intermediary.  The existing design works but now I need to filter the Project by a third table.

In english - I have a Organization (Django) and which points to many Projects (Legacy).  But all of the Project don't refer to that Organization.  I have a third table ProjectMap which was build via a Trigger to address that.  It corresponds the Organization.name to a project.

How do I glue this together in order allow me to do this.

```
projects = Organization.objects.get(pk=1).projects.all()
```

And it won't get ALL of the projects just the ones which match in the third table.  Here is what I have so far..

*By the way if anyone has a better strategy I'm all ears*

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project)

class Project(models.Model):
    """This is the project info page..

    Note: 'id' does exist and is the pk.
    """
    result_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column='LBLDGRUNNO', blank=True) 
    building_number = models.IntegerField(db_column='LBLDGNO') 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_column='SPIBLGNAME', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'PROJINFO'
        managed = False

class ProjectMap(models.Model):
    projinfo_table_id = models.IntegerField(null=True) # 'id' of Project
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True) # 'name' in Organization
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what your asking, but you can use the `through` call on the ManyToManyField to define an intermediate table:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, through="ProjectOrganisation")

class Project(models.Model):
    #Stuff Here

class ProjectOrganisation(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    #Other Fields Here
```

Django does this automatically with manytomany fields anyway, just if you want to add extra fields, this is the way to do it.

Comment: This would be easier but not possible given the constraints in that a trigger is what creates the Map table it won't work for me.  Wishful thinking but thanks!!

Comment: After a significant amount of rework (including a dive into MySQL triggers - oh boy..) this is the direction I ended up going.  Thanks!